# Create calculated measure in cognos framework manager using count function with condition

Tags: database, business-intelligence, cognos

I have a database for hotels and each record represents a hotel with different facts related to this specific hotel for example the grading the category of the hotel whether hotel or hotel apartments etc..., What i want to do is to count all the records with the 'Hotel' Accom Type how can i achieve this as i tried to do it using count but it counts all the records not the ones with the Accom Type I look for attached a screenshot of the records,
Any Help will be appreciated

[image: The Table snap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two patterns:

```
COUNT(
    CASE [Accom Type] 
    WHEN 'Hotel' THEN [Accom Type] 
    ELSE null
    END
)
```

or

```
TOTAL(
    CASE [Accom Type] 
    WHEN 'Hotel' THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END
)
```